# How to draw the UK map?

Tags: html, maps

I have a database, one of tables contain client list with addresses+UK Postcode.
I'd like to draw map of UK and display diagram with amount of clients in each UK region.
What should I use? Any template?

Comment: That depends on a lot of things. One of the important factors you have not mentioned is what kind of coordinates you use for your clients. Different maps are drawn with different coordinates. If you put coordinates from one system on top of a map in another you're not going to have a representative map. Some clients might end up in the sea

Comment: Try leaflet maps, use coordinates to put markers.

Comment: I have UK Postcodes of clients and want to use them to display on the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a js library called d3.js that can draw interactive maps.

More infos here : https://datamaps.github.io/ and here : https://d3js.org/

Comment: Ok, thnx, how to draw it using sanddance? It allows to create interactive charts and graphs in 3D: https://sanddance.js.org/app/